# spring kafka registerListenerContainer method startImmediately flag true or false?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am using spring boot 2.7 + kafka 3.0.

I have a bean in my configuration as below to define the KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.

In this bean, I need to register my listener with method registerListenerContainer.

```
  @Bean(name = KafkaListenerConfigUtils.KAFKA_LISTENER_ENDPOINT_REGISTRY_BEAN_NAME)
   public KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry defaultKafkaListenerEndpointRegistry(Map<String, RetryConfig> retryConfigMap) {
        return new KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry() {
            @Override
            public void registerListenerContainer(
                    KafkaListenerEndpoint endpoint, KafkaListenerContainerFactory<?> factory) {
                // register original one
                MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint<Object, Object> methodEndpoint = (MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint<Object, Object>) endpoint;
                String originalTopic = new ArrayList<String>(endpoint.getTopics()).get(0);
               

                super.registerListenerContainer(methodEndpoint, factory);
                ...
                
            }
        };
    }
```

The method registerListenerContainer has a property startImmediately which by default is false, Should I set it to true, From the doc it says:

> The startImmediately flag determines if the container should be
> started immediately.

But This is really not clear to me, what's the difference of the different setting? and what impact would it be if set to false?

Comment: Well, do you want your KafkaListener annotated functions to start consuming immediately or not?

Comment: I want to set to false, which is not to consuming immediatelly. But the start immediately flag is set up 3 years ago together with the kafka configuration in my project. I am not  100% sure what's the difference and the impact will be, From business perspective, I need to make sure the changes does not impact our business.

Comment: I'm not sure why time is relevant if you want the behavior you've described

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set it to `false`, then you have to start a container for that endpoint manually later. Use `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainer(String id)` API to call its `start()`. Otherwise it is started automatically by the ApplicationContext lifecycle: or after the whole refresh, or immediately if you register that endpoint at runtime.

Not clear, though, why would one do that `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry` overriding if in most cases the `@KafkaListener` is enough. The topic retry can be handled by the `RetryableTopic`.

Comment: Hi, Yes spring application context will start the container when start the beans in our case if set to false. 
With regard to override KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry, there are historic reasons, the override configuration was set up about three years ago to register the listener and the retry. From spring docs:
Starting with version 2.2, you can now override the container factory’s concurrency and autoStartup properties...
Maybe in that time the KafkaListener had not support the autoStart control.
Will need to do some refactor to use RetryableTopic later.

Comment: And for us there is always some waring logs when setting the startImmediatelly to true: UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION. when run our test who integrated with Kafka.  root cause is that:
tests is runing in  docker container with fresh Kafka broker. So each time when registing the listener container in the config, The topics who created by the NewTopics Bean are actually not created in the kafka broker yet, then there will be a lots of warning logs, this really bothering us.
Based on our use case, I will try to change the flag to false.  Thanks for your explanation and suggestion

Comment: @Ray spring-kafka-test has an embedded Kafka broker class where you can provide it topics to create at startup. This would be quicker than pulling/waiting for a container

Comment: @OneCricketeer,Yes You are right, that's another option which I also figured out,  But it would need to add some test configuration, and also I need to specify all the topics which my app used(including original topic and retry topic).
This way it can also solve the warning logs, just as you said, its quicker.

We would prefer to use NewTopic beans to create topics. And then the topic create is slower so then we have to set the startImmediatelly as false.